# General formula for calculating $\prod_{i \in I}(1-a_i)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Does anyone know the general formula for calculating $\prod_{i \in I}(1-a_i)$ where $I$ is a set of indices?
I suspect it is $1+\sum_{\emptyset \subsetneq J \subseteq I}(-1)^{|J|}\prod_{j \in J}a_j$. I don't require a proof, just a confirmation.

Comment: Looks almost fine. You should write either $\sum_{\emptyset \ne J \subseteq I}$ or omit the "$1$", as $(-1)^{|\emptyset|}\prod_{j \in \emptyset} a_j = 1$ gives the second "$1$" now, which you don't need.

Comment: Done the edit as suggested.

Comment: Now you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have by distributivity
\begin{align*}
  \prod_{i\in I} (1 - a_i) &= \sum_{J \subseteq I}  \prod_{j \in J} (-a_j) \cdot \prod_{j \in I \setminus J} 1 \\
      &= \sum_{J \subseteq I} (-1)^{|J|} \prod_{j \in J} a_j\\
      &= 1 + \sum_{\emptyset \ne J \subseteq I} (-1)^{|J|} \prod_{j \in J} a_j
\end{align*}